# backslashes in string in streamreader

Tags: c#, csv

I have an odd problem.

I try to read a csv file for a datamigration. This is how the file looks (its UTF8 formatted)

```
"MIGRATIONID","ACCOUNTID","MIGRACCOUNTID","CONFIGID","MEDIUMID","PRIMCLASSID","SECCLASSID","SALESCODE","CONTENT","REGELNR","LIST_ATTRIBUTES","PACKAGE_TYPE","VERWIJSADVERTENTIE","NIET_PUBLICEREN"
"ITM-0015-0163","62222532","ACT-0000-4755","61635591","TGP","TG_P_GV_01","","TG_Print_GV","%NAME%|%STREETNAME%|%HOUSENUMBER%|%HOUSENUMBEREXT%||%POSTALCODE%|%LOCALITY%|%AREACODE%|%CONNECTIONNUMBER%|%URL%|%EMAIL%||%COMMERCIAL%||||||%PRODNR%","10","","","","FALSE"
"ITM-0015-0172","62222140","ACT-0000-4779","61636356","TGP","TG_P_GV_01","","TG_Print_GV","%NAME%|%STREETNAME%|%HOUSENUMBER%|%HOUSENUMBEREXT%||%POSTALCODE%|%LOCALITY%|%AREACODE%|%CONNECTIONNUMBER%|%URL%|%EMAIL%||%COMMERCIAL%||||||%PRODNR%","10","","","","FALSE"
```

As you can see, it is comma separated.

I read it using a streamreader:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(documentFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //perform the transformation
}
```

I have done this a million times without problems. However, when the rows are read, they suddenly turn up like this (copied from the debug watch):

```
"\"ITM-0015-0163\",\"62222532\",\"ACT-0000-4755\",\"61635591\",\"TGP\",\"TG_P_GV_01\",\"\",\"TG_Print_GV\",\"%NAME%|%STREETNAME%|%HOUSENUMBER%|%HOUSENUMBEREXT%||%POSTALCODE%|%LOCALITY%|%AREACODE%|%CONNECTIONNUMBER%|%URL%|%EMAIL%||%COMMERCIAL%||||||%PRODNR%\",\"10\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"FALSE\""
```

Where do all these backslashes come from? Am i reading the file wrong. How can i prevent this? Because it wrecks up my further processing of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debugger just shows the value like it would appear in a literal in code (note that it's surrounded by quotation marks, too). You can click the little magnifying glass to open a text-only view which will not put backslashes there.

If you doubt this you can just write the text you read to the console to verify it.

Comment: Sir, you are right! The problem turns out not to be the backslashes, but the double-quotes! Many thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2):

They're just an artifact of the debug view. The string actually contains just a `"`, but the debug view displays it as `\"`. Write the string to the console, or show a message box, and you'll see those `\` aren't actually there.

This allows you to see if `"` is just a `"` contained in the string, or an `"` that terminates the string. It's the same syntax used for string literals in C#.

Whatever wrecks up your further processing of the data, it's not the escaping of `"` you see in the debug view.

Comment: Actually, i am using the first colum to build a diretory path, and the backslash caused an exception in the path creation. Thatswhy i found out about this problem. Hence it is not limited to the debugger.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil then either your example string is wrong, or you misdiagnosed the problem. Your example string does not contain any `\`es.

Answer (score 1):

You read quotes as well. Combination backslash + quote is shown only in debugger (c# strings...), otherwise it's just a quote.

If you don't need them, trim the column values.

EDIT: I can see in the comments that you're creating folders using the value of the first column for the name. Folder names cannot contain `"`